# Russia roadmap with information on the surface

Tags: driving, planning, russia, maps

In Russia, some segments of major highways are of mediocre quality:

[image: Russian road, no tarmac]

Russia road M53 / Baikal Highway, near Taishet. [Source: Wikimedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:M53road.jpg)

[image: Russian road, bad tarmac]

Russian [Trans-Siberian highway](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trans-Siberian_Highway) near Cheremshanka, Krasnoyarsk Kray. [Source](http://www.panoramio.com/photo/59452639).  (NB: Old photo; this section of road has since been surfaced with tarmac)

For planning purposes it can be useful to know if roads have tarmac or not.
Even better is to know the quality of the tarmac.
Are there any maps for Russia that show now only where the highways are, but also contain information about the road surface?

Comment: How's your Russian?

Comment: @Karlson Poor, but for a map I'd need to look up just a handful of words in the map key...

Answer (score 7):

According to the article in [motor.ru](http://motor.ru/news/2012/03/21/without/) there is a [portal](http://www.goodroads.ru) that is supposed to provide up to date road conditions.  Not sure if it has never took off or this is still pending but [Google](http://www.rusdorogi.ru/) actually has an app for Android that will allow you to see current conditions of the road surface.

Answer (score 7):

One advice for you if you planning to ride Russia on car. In general, spring is time when roads are in most poor state. End of summer is time when roads are mostly repaired. Middle of it is a hell of continuous repairs and as a result of them -  traffic jams even on federal roads.

Also one site for you with info about russian towns.(It has info about different countries but Russia is there too)   [tema.ru](http://www.tema.ru/travel/cities/russian/). You may translate it via Google translate.

Answer (score 5):

If it wasn't so sad, in Russia it is really the Problem is very serious. Of course not all areas are terrible roads. however, it is recognized that there are areas in which there is simply no roads! (although the navigation map might show a federal highway of European quality.)! There is even a proverb about this which translates roughly as: Russia has two problems: fools and roads! I do not think referring to maps or other online sources you get the information you need. Because of my work, I traveled almost the entire country, and I can say what roads and in what capacity at a particular site. if you're interested - you can feel free to write to me personally. Skype or email I will help you.